# How to add www to images?

Tags: site-url

I have site with the `http://domain.com` but I want to have `http://www.domain.com` so I have changed it in Settings.

It's working great now for all pages and posts. But for images and all attachments, it still `domain.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/`. How can I change it on `www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/`?

Comment: When you say images, do you mean those already inserted into posts? Or do you mean all images and attachments, both new and old? Are you referring to other things aside from those inside posts too?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Velvet Blues Update URLs wordpress plugin.

I had used velvet blue update urls plugin many times while migrating wordpress site from one domain to another. please select attachment option in that.

Link For [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/)

[image]

Old Url Use "http://example.com" & In new Url use "http://www.example.com" & Check All the Options then your problem Fixed.

Comment: Hello, thank you. But it doesn't work. It says that 1509 attachments are updated but it still show as domain.com/... not www.domain.com/...

Comment: See my edited comment above. do that steps And don't forget to check all options. It will fix your issue.